# Triangular region for the stationarity of a bivariate process

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics, stochastic-processes

Consider the bivariate stochastic process:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
y_t = \alpha y_{t-1} + x_t + \epsilon_t \\
x_t = x_{t-1} + \beta y_{t-1} + \nu_t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

with a bivariate white noise {$\epsilon_t,\nu_t$}.

Find the admissible triangular region of the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the stationarity of the bivariate process {$y_t, x_t$}.
Hint: use the admissible triangular region of parameters for any AR(2).

The solution is
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-2(1+\alpha) < \beta < 0 \\
-1<\alpha<1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I am not able to understand how to prove the solution.

Comment: I am not very familiar with autoregressive models, but if you find an expression for $x_{t-1}$ based on $y_{t-1}$ and $y_{t-2}$ using the first equation, and then substitute the $x_t$ in the second equation using the first one, and also substitute $x_{t-1}$ using the expression you just found, and make sure that the distribution of the noise is what you need it to be, you find an AR(2) model that only depends on the $y$ time series.

Comment: I tired and I obtained: $y_t = (\alpha + 1 + \beta)y_{t-1}-\alpha y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-2}+\nu_t$ but its triangular region is different respect to the one provided in the solutions.

Comment: I used the characterization in here http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/12081 that, if the process is $Y_t=\phi_1 Y_{t-1}+\phi_2 Y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t$, then the triangular region is defined by the constraints $\phi_2-\phi_1<1$, $\phi_2+\phi_1<1$, $|\phi_2|<1$. Replace $\phi_1=\alpha+\beta+1$, $\phi_2=-\alpha$, group similar terms, and we obtain the solution you mention.

Comment: You can simply upvote my comment if you are concerned about my reputation score, thank you! You got the same AR(2) that I got, so I wouldn't add much to you if I wrote down the steps!